# Why accessing page_range is different in shell and template?

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am totally new in Django and currently learning pagination. This question confused me and I need your help to help me understand it.

In order to access `page_range` value in shell, I directly type in `pages.page_range` as code below:

```
>>> from django.core.paginator import Paginator
>>> posts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> pages = Paginator(posts, 2)
>>> pages.page_range  # here
range(1, 5)
```

but in template in order to access `page_range` value we need to type in `page_obj.paginator.page_range`.

The question is why it is throwing an error if I access `page_range` without `.paginator` mediation like `page_obj.page_range`, since in shell we don't need to type `pages.paginator.page_range`?

Please help me understand what I am missing here. Thank you

edit: Does `page_obj` has other meaning other than current page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `page_obj` is not an instance of `Paginator` class. It is an instance of `Page` class which has `paginator` object associated with it. (See source [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/paginator.py#L139)). So definitely you have to access anything from `paginator` object like this `page_obj.paginator.page_range`.

However paginator object itself is also passed to context (See source [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L119)). You can access it directly if you want like this `paginator.page_range`